# VS 2012: 'Add Installer' from Windows Service not working

Tags: windows-services

Created a windows service in VS2012.  Right clicked on the service and selected 'Add Installer' as done in VS2010

Got the message:

> Unable to add installer.  The designer could not add a Project Installer.

Anybody run into this ?

Answer (score 13):

Check to see if the files already exist.  In my case, a previous developer excluded the installer files from the project, so I did not see them until I opened a Windows Explorer on the source folder.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an Express version?  I have not run into this problem with Visual Studio Professional 2012 on Windows 8 N Pro.  I can right click on the designer surface and click on item "Add Installer" and a class is created called 'ProjectInstaller'.

You can create the project installer class manually.  Designers are overrated anyway.  I have written a blog article on how to do this.
[Simple Installer for Windows Service Using Visual Studio 2012](http://candordeveloper.com/2012/12/28/simple-installer-for-windows-service-using-visual-studio-2012/)

Is there a reason you need a deployment wizard?  Is there a configuration parameter you need to prompt the installing user with?  I generally just use a configuration file and package up each environment's configuration with the deployable.

Comment: Thank you for creating the write-up, that saved from having to do a lot of research.

Comment: Thanks for this too. When I heard there was a "designer", it scared me.. how the hell is dragging and dropping gonna translate to deploying this in production? Damn Microsoft and their arcane practices!

Answer (score 0):

The Project Installer is not included in VS 2012.  If you right click your solution and choose Add, New Project, then go to Other Project Types and choose Setup and Deployment, it should take you to the InstallShield page where you can download and install the Limited edition of InstallShield for free (you will have to register and get an activation code via email).  Once installed, repeat the steps above and it should prompt you to either register the software or continue with a trial version.